# Unity Sprites - Collider not working Properly

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was following a tutorial on how to create a simple game called pong. As I was working on it. I stumbled on a bug that when the ball is to fast it will  it passes through the paddle without colliding with the collider

As you can see in the screenshot

[image]

Is this some kind of a bug in unity? I need to get rid of this and don't want to have this in my game.

by the way this was the tutorial I was following .  [Brackeys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQXdREL4GGg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by 'bypass the player control'? Do you mean it passes through the paddle without colliding with the collider, even though it should? Or does it get stuck? The screenshot makes it difficult to tell.

Either way, the first thing you're going to want to try is changing the collision detection setting of your Rigidbody2D component from 'Discrete' (the default value) to 'Continuous' or 'Continuous Dynamic'. Fixing this sort of issue (collision errors for fast-moving objects) is exactly what those options are for.

Source: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html

Comment: oh. sorry. it was " it passes through the paddle without colliding with the collider"

Comment: i see. ill try what you suggest

Comment: Damn. Did you change the setting on all of the Rigidbodies or just one?

Comment: oh no. sorry. You were right :),, I I haven't change the Collision Detection on the paddle. only on the ball. my bad